# Get Active TabName

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I want to get active tabname. I am aware it is possible using id parameter in sidebarmenu and then call it using input$id in server. I can't use this functionality as I have customised sidebar which does not return selected (or active) tab name. Hence I want to solve it using javascript. I tried this using JS 
`$('.tab-content').find('.active').attr('data-value')` but it is not working properly.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


jscode <- "shinyjs.gettab = function () {
 $('.tab-content').find('.active').attr('data-value')
 }"

  ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Use of JS"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "HOME",
          tabName = "home",
          icon = icon("home")
        ),
        menuItem(
          text = "MAP",
          tabName = "map",
          icon = icon("map")
        )
    )),
    dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      extendShinyjs(text = jscode)

    ))

  server = function(input, output) { 

    observe({ print(js$gettab()) })

    }

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser =T)
```